# PHP HTML Parsing the giving URL

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm kinda new to PHP. I have found some examples for HTML parsing with PHP but I couldn't make any one work. I have tried the "SimpleHtmlDom", but I can work with anything provided instructions, LAMP server is running locally, so I can install libraries or whatever is needed (preferably free).

I don't know if the URL is the cause of my problem. So, here is my problem

**The URL:** http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/temas.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=150010

Inside this URL there is a table, and inside this table, are the information I need.

`<table class="dados">...</table>`

From this table, inside the given URL, I only want the column with the numbers.

Is that something supposedly simple? If anyone give me the solution, I wouldn't mind learn what's going on, but the solution alone would be freak'n great ;)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SimpleHtmlDom      will give you the values column easily :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$string = ' <table class="dados"> <thead> <tr> <th colspan="5" class="pesquisa">Síntese das Informações </th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td class="titulo">Área da unidade territorial</td><td class="valor">159.533,730</td><td class="unidade">km²</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v01&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v01&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Estabelecimentos de Saúde SUS</td><td class="valor">46</td><td class="unidade">estabelecimentos</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v02&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v02&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Índice de Desenvolvimento Humano Municipal - 2010 (IDHM 2010)</td><td class="valor">0,665</td><td class="unidade">&nbsp;</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v20&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v20&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Matrícula - Ensino fundamental - 2012</td><td class="valor">19.990</td><td class="unidade">matrículas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v03&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v03&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Matrícula - Ensino médio - 2012</td><td class="valor">5.952</td><td class="unidade">matrículas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v04&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v04&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Número de unidades locais</td><td class="valor">1.866</td><td class="unidade">unidades</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v05&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v05&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Pessoal ocupado total</td><td class="valor">19.297</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v06&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v06&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">PIB per capita a preços correntes - 2011</td><td class="valor">8.841,19</td><td class="unidade">reais</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v07&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v07&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente </td><td class="valor">99.075</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v08&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v08&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente - Homens</td><td class="valor">49.819</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v09&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v09&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente - Mulheres</td><td class="valor">49.256</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v10&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v10&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente alfabetizada</td><td class="valor">77.016</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v11&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v11&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente que frequentava creche ou escola </td><td class="valor">34.797</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v12&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v12&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente, religião católica apostólica romana</td><td class="valor">54.487</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v13&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v13&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente, religião espírita</td><td class="valor">234</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v14&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v14&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">População residente, religião evangélicas</td><td class="valor">26.666</td><td class="unidade">pessoas</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v15&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v15&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Valor do rendimento nominal mediano mensal per capita dos domicílios particulares permanentes - Rural</td><td class="valor">166,67</td><td class="unidade">reais</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v18&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v18&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Valor do rendimento nominal mediano mensal per capita dos domicílios particulares permanentes - Urbana</td><td class="valor">360,00</td><td class="unidade">reais</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v19&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v19&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Valor do rendimento nominal médio mensal dos domicílios particulares permanentes com rendimento domiciliar, por situação do domicílio - Rural</td><td class="valor">1.342,96</td><td class="unidade">reais</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v16&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v16&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr><tr><td class="titulo">Valor do rendimento nominal médio mensal dos domicílios particulares permanentes com rendimento domiciliar, por situação do domicílio - Urbana</td><td class="valor">2.010,04</td><td class="unidade">reais</td><td class="link_cartograma"><a href="../cartograma/mapa.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;codmun=150060&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v17&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Ver cartograma">Ver cartograma</a></td><td class="link_comparativo"><a href="../comparamun/compara.php?lang=&amp;coduf=15&amp;idtema=16&amp;codv=v17&amp;search=para|altamira|sintese-das-informacoes-" title="Comparar com outros municípios">Comparar com outros municípios</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table>    ';


$html = str_get_html($string);

foreach($html->find('td.valor') as $element){
echo $element.'<br />';
}
```

This will give you this result

159.533,730
46
0,665
19.990
5.952
1.866
19.297
8.841,19
99.075
49.819
49.256
77.016
34.797
54.487
234
26.666
166,67
360,00
1.342,96
2.010,04

Comment: JohnTaa, thank you. Thank you very much.Can you help me getting the table from the URL? The reason I need this parser is that I'll get data from several pages like the one I provided, using "codmun" parameter to change the subject. But all I need is one example, the loop I can do myself, parsing the is my only problem. I only gave away the table code so you could take a look, but the table is inside the given URL. If you could take a look at http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/csv.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=1304104 source, you can see what I mean.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not mentioning it, but the code you posted worked, the number extraction, all I need now is parse the numbers from the URL ;)

Comment: The given Url is not html page but a csv file

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the URL, the correct one is http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/temas.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=150010

Comment: Yeah man. It was my mistake. I posted the correct one above and changed the OP. Sorry about that. Thank you very much for your efforts helping me.

Comment: `<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require('./simple_html_dom.php');

$string = file_get_html('http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/temas.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=150010');

$html = str_get_html($string);

foreach($html->find('td.valor') as $element){
 echo $element.';';
}

?>` didn't work

Comment: <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');      require('./simple_html_dom.php'); 

    $string = file_get_contents('http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/temas.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=150010'); 
 
    $html = str_get_html($string); foreach($html->find(' td.valor') as $element){ echo $element.';'; } ?>

Comment: Hum... it didn't worked here. I copied and pasted your code, replacing the URL, that was shortened by StackOverflow. I believe my problem is fetching the URL content with _file_get_contents_ or _file_get_html_. Do I need any special configuration on apache or PHP.ini? When I used your first example, it worked fine, so I believe my problem is actually getting the URL content.

Comment: **I also have tried the following:** `$context = stream_context_create();
(stream_context_set_params($context,
  array(
       'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36',
      'header'=>'Accept-language: en\r\n')
     )
 );
$html = file_get_html('http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/temas.php?lang=&idtema=16&codmun=150010', 0, $context);` **but no joy**

Comment: **Solved with your last solution**. My server went offline, don't know why. **JohnTaa**, thank you for your patience.

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

you can indeed use DOM manipulation, but if you really just want the colunm with the numbers you could use just a simple regular expresion like this one:

```
preg_match_all('/valor">(.[^<]*)</', $HTML, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Carlos Rocha beat me to this, but I am putting example here anyway)

You can parse any text (including HTML) with `preg_match_all` and save the results to an array. In your case you want to look for the column with class `valor` and grab the inner HTML.

Full example for you:

```
<?php

$str = '<table class="dados"> <thead> ... <td class="valor">159.533,730</td><td class="valor">46</td> ... ';
preg_match_all("@valor\">(.*?)<@", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```